# Magento2 - Get product Ids matching to shopping cart rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I need to get the product Ids, matching to the cart rule, in my cron job.

I looked on some posts in `stackoverflow`, but in those answers, product is loaded for each rule.

I don't want to load each product again and again.

Somebody suggest a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `SKU` as it is the best way as sometimes products can get **deleted** and **re-added** and hence in the future there could be issue

Also using **SKU** is default